# Cqlengine queries: how to return dictionary?

Tags: python, django, dictionary, cassandra, cqlengine

I'm using cqlengine in Django application, where Cassandra is the secondary database.

In some cases I need to join manually the results of SQL and NoSQL database requests.

For SQL I'm using:

```
model_name.objects.all().values()
```

to return dictionary, rather than model-instance objects.

But I can't find the appropriate methods in `cqlengine`.

As a beginner in python, I do not know how best to implement this functionality within `cqlengine` library.

Maybe you have some examples of program code, providing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to use a generator for loop like such:

```
[dict(foo) for foo in Bar.objects.all()]
```

That will return a dictionary of all the objects and depending on your code base will allow you to do custom serialization and deserialization.

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
And if I need to get not all fields, but only some of them, and present the result as a dictionary? 
I've found how to filter fields using values_list(), but the result - is list. 
Is there any other way?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using that, considering CQLEngine has it's own built in functionality to handle it...  I wouldn't use values_list() either.  Have you read the official documentation before using the module?

Answer (score 2):

There is built-in functionality for this as of cqlengine 0.12.  This is per:  [CQLEngine Model Docs](http://cqlengine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/models.html#manipulating-model-instances-as-dictionaries)

> As of cqlengine 0.12, we’ve added support for treating model instances like dictionaries. See below for examples.

```
class Person(Model):
first_name  = columns.Text()
last_name = columns.Text()

kevin = Person.create(first_name="Kevin", last_name="Deldycke")
dict(kevin)  # returns {'first_name': 'Kevin', 'last_name': 'Deldycke'}
kevin['first_name']  # returns 'Kevin'
kevin.keys()  # returns ['first_name', 'last_name']
kevin.values()  # returns ['Kevin', 'Deldycke']
kevin.items()  # returns [('first_name', 'Kevin'), ('last_name', 'Deldycke')]

kevin['first_name'] = 'KEVIN5000'  # changes the models first name
```

So, to answer your question... You'll want to just do a basic query, get your objects and on that, convert it to a dict:

```
dict(your_returned_model_object)
```

You can now access the returned objects as a dictionary, like it's referenced above.